# How to remove header in Anthos Service Mesh?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio, google-anthos

When I started using Anthos Service Mesh, the following custom headers were added. Is there a way to remove the corresponding header through setup without removing it from the mTLS setup or code level?

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-length: 145
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: text/plain
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Mon, 24 Jul 2023 07:41:32 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: istio-envoy
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-envoy-decorator-operation: stage-app.stage-app.svc.cluster.local:8000/*
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: via: 1.1 google
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111
```

```
x-envoy-decorator-operation: stage-app.stage-app.svc.cluster.local:8000/*
```

I've tried setting up mTLS, but I don't know what I misconfigured, but that won't make network communication work.

The reason I want to clear the corresponding header is because the namespace and port of the cluster are exposed.
If you set up mTLS on Istio, the corresponding header automatically disappears, but I don't want to set it up separately.

Comment: Your post is confusing. Why do you want to remove the Envoy header? How is that header related to mTLS? Edit your post to add more context.

Comment: I comment more information.

Comment: There's an active work item around this issue: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/17635 

One of the solutions is to use an egress gateway to scrub the propagation headers.